# Port Knocking on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos

Does anyone know how to get [Port Knocking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking) work on macOS Sierra. I couldn't find any useful information after a search.

It works now, thanks for all the help. @klanomath  @jksoegaard. Wish you all the best.

Here are the configurations:

1. Configuration: /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt is empty initially
2. Configuration: /etc/pf.conf

   ```
   scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
   nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
   rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
   dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
   anchor "com.apple/*"
   load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
   table <ssh-access> persist file "/usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt"
   pass in quick proto tcp from <ssh-access> to port 22
   ```
3. Configuration: /usr/local/etc/knockd.conf

   ```
   [options]
           logfile = /var/log/knockd.log
   [openSSH]
           sequence    = 7000,8000,9000
           seq_timeout = 5
           command     = echo %IP% > /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt
           tcpflags    = syn
   [commitFW]
           sequence    = 9000,8000,7000
           seq_timeout = 5
           command     = pfctl -t ssh-access -T replace -f /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt
           tcpflags    = syn
   [closeSSH]
           sequence    = 5000,4000,6000
           seq_timeout = 5
           command     = echo '' > /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt
           tcpflags    = syn
   ```
4. Output when Launch knockd:

   ```
   config: new section: 'options'
   config: log file: /var/log/knockd.log
   config: new section: 'openSSH'
   config: openSSH: sequence: 7000:tcp,8000:tcp,9000:tcp
   config: openSSH: seq_timeout: 5
   config: openSSH: start_command: echo %IP% > /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt
   config: tcp flag: SYN
   config: new section: 'commitFW'
   config: commitFW: sequence: 9000:tcp,8000:tcp,7000:tcp
   config: commitFW: seq_timeout: 5
   config: commitFW: start_command: pfctl -t ssh-access -T replace -f /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt
   config: tcp flag: SYN
   config: new section: 'closeSSH'
   config: closeSSH: sequence: 5000:tcp,4000:tcp,6000:tcp
   config: closeSSH: seq_timeout: 5
   config: closeSSH: start_command: echo '' > /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt
   config: tcp flag: SYN
   ethernet interface detected
   Local IP: 192.168.8.101
   Adding pcap expression for door 'openSSH': (dst host 192.168.8.101 and (((tcp dst port 7000 or 8000 or 9000) and tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn != 0)))
   Adding pcap expression for door 'commitFW': (dst host 192.168.8.101 and (((tcp dst port 9000 or 8000 or 7000) and tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn != 0)))
   Adding pcap expression for door 'closeSSH': (dst host 192.168.8.101 and (((tcp dst port 5000 or 4000 or 6000) and tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn != 0)))
   ```
5. Knock from client Mac

   ```
   192:~ vincent-st$ knock -v 192.168.8.101 7000,8000,9000
   hitting tcp 192.168.8.101:7000
   192:~ vincent-st$ knock -v 192.168.8.101 9000,8000,7000
   hitting tcp 192.168.8.101:9000
   192:~ vincent-st$ ssh vincent-st@192.168.8.101
   ssh: connect to host  port 22: connection refused
   ```

---

After using the proper knock command ssh works:

6. Knock from client Mac

   ```
   192:~ vincent-st$ knock -v 192.168.8.101 7000 8000 9000
   hitting tcp 192.168.8.101:7000
   hitting tcp 192.168.8.101:8000
   hitting tcp 192.168.8.101:9000

   192:~ vincent-st$ knock -v 192.168.8.101 9000 8000 7000
   hitting tcp 192.168.8.101:9000
   hitting tcp 192.168.8.101:8000
   hitting tcp 192.168.8.101:7000

   192:~ vincent-st$ ssh vincent-st@192.168.8.101
   The authenticity of host '192.168.8.101 (192.168.8.101)' can't be established.

   RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:6AlMpQmxODOueRS+faoODOueRS+ODOueRS+fa.
   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
   Warning: Permanently added '192.168.8.101' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

   Password:

   Last login: Tue Jul 11 01:14:56 2017 `
   ```

Comment: Slowly transforming a question into an answer **in the question**  by editing the question repeatedly isn't very meaningful because the original problem gets lost. Usually it's better to write a 2nd answer mentioning all the hurdles, improper configs or errors you made etc (even so a proper answer is already posted).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to get port knocking working as a client (i.e. you want to access a remote service that is protected by port knocking) - then install the knock program from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) like this:

```
brew install knock
```

You'll need to have Homebrew installed in advance.

Then you can use the program from Terminal.app like this:

```
knock myserver 1234 5678 9012
```

where the numbers are the ports to knock.

If you need to get port knocking working as a server (i.e. you want to protect a local resource so that remote access is limited to those in-the-know by port knocking) - then similarly install knock from Homebrew.

After installation you'll need to create a knockd.conf configuration customized to your requirements (i.e. which type of service you want to protect, the ports to use, etc.) - and finally start knockd using launchd.

You can find an example of how to do this here:

[Example knockd setup](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/61m5md/port_knock_server_on_macos/)

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs, sir. I did try this before asking for help. I have homebrew installed, and run brew install knock to install knock on my server. Then, I created an empty file: /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt, and edit the file /usr/local/etc/knockd.conf as the link suggests, then run the command: /usr/local/sbin/knockd -dDv -i en0 -c /usr/local/etc/knockd.conf. I still could ssh into the server without port knocking.

Comment: This is because you skipped the pf skip in the link in my post. You have to add to pf.conf (the firewall configuration) that access to port 22 (ssh) is only allowed to those listed in the ssh-access.txt file. This is the file that is updated by knockd.

Comment: Yes, that's the part which confuses me. I have no idea how to add pf.conf which accesses to port 22 to the ssh-access.txt file.                I tried to add the server IP and port to the /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt, but I'm not sure if it's correct. After all this was done. I tried to knock from the client Mac. Here is what it looks like (pictures are shows in the question).

Comment: Just follow the instructions in the link I gave you. It shows what to write in the pf.conf file. You should not manually add anything to ssh-access.txt - so just delete that file and recreate it empty as the instructions states.

Comment: @jksoegaard latest package also needs `/usr/local/sbin`, in my case it was not created so I've created and given permissions. Could you expand answer?,  this might be helpful for others.