# Port knocking on macOS not blocking connections when closed

Tags: macos, mojave

I'm unable to get the `pf` packet filter to block ssh connections when the knockd port-knocking system is in a closed state.

- I've followed instructions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290287/port-knocking-on-macos-sierra)
- I've verified [`knockd`](http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock) is running from its logfile and is executing the open/close/commit commands.
- I've verified `pf` is running using the `pfctl -E` command.

Here is my configuration:

`/etc/pf.conf:`

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
table <ssh-access> persist file "/usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt"
pass in quick proto tcp from <ssh-access> to port 22
```

`/usr/local/etc/knockd.conf:`

```
[options]
        logfile = /var/log/knockd.log

[openSSH]
        sequence    = 7000,8000,9000
        seq_timeout = 5
        command     = echo %IP% > /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt
        tcpflags    = syn

[closeSSH]
        sequence    = 9000,8000,7000
        seq_timeout = 5
        command     = echo '' > /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt
        tcpflags    = syn
[commitFW]
        sequence    = 5000,4000,6000
        seq_timeout = 5
        command     = pfctl -t ssh-access -T replace -f /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt
        tcpflags    = syn
```

Started `knockd` with the following command (my Mac mini is on wifi so using `en1`)

```
/usr/local/sbin/knockd -dDv -i en1 -c /usr/local/etc/knockd.conf
```

Output from `/var/log/knockd.log`:

```
[2019-06-02 16:13] starting up, listening on en1
[2019-06-02 16:14] 192.168.1.30: closeSSH: Stage 1
[2019-06-02 16:14] 192.168.1.30: closeSSH: Stage 2
[2019-06-02 16:14] 192.168.1.30: closeSSH: Stage 3
[2019-06-02 16:14] 192.168.1.30: closeSSH: OPEN SESAME
[2019-06-02 16:14] closeSSH: running command: echo '' > /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt

[2019-06-02 16:15] 192.168.1.30: commitFW: Stage 1
[2019-06-02 16:15] 192.168.1.30: commitFW: Stage 2
[2019-06-02 16:15] 192.168.1.30: commitFW: Stage 3
[2019-06-02 16:15] 192.168.1.30: commitFW: OPEN SESAME
[2019-06-02 16:15] commitFW: running command: pfctl -t ssh-access -T replace -f /usr/local/etc/ssh-access.txt
```

But I'm still able to `ssh` from other machines on my network into this one.